# Unity - how to set a value in an array on a prefab on instantiation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I instantiate a number of prefabs and need to set the paths. The path nodes are between 1 and 3 sections long.

```
public GameObject mb;

void Start()
    {
        GameObject planeIcon;
        foreach (PlaneData p in PlaneManager.planesData)
        {
            if(p.route != 0)
            {
                planeIcon = Instantiate(iconPrefab);
                planeIcon.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(p.planeFilename + "_icon");
                planeIcon.name = p.planeName;
                planeIcon.GetComponent<AnimatePlane>().moveSpeed = p.planeSpeed;
                planeIcon.GetComponent<AnimatePlane>().range = p.planeRange;

                planeIcon.GetComponent<AnimatePlane>().pathNode[0] = mb;
}
```

this throws an IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array on the last line

The AnimatePlane code is attached to the prefab that is instantiated above

```
public class AnimatePlane : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] pathNode = new GameObject[3];
    public float moveSpeed;
    public int range;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("pathnode length: " + pathNode.Length);
        CheckNode();
    }
```

Debug output is show pathnode length = 0
I'm assuming I need to initialise the array somehow in the AnimatePlane code, but can't think what I'm missing.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this.

```
    public GameObject mb;
    
    void Start()
        {
            GameObject planeIcon;
            foreach (PlaneData p in PlaneManager.planesData)
            {
                if(p.route != 0)
                {
                    planeIcon = Instantiate(iconPrefab);
                    planeIcon.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(p.planeFilename + "_icon");
                    planeIcon.name = p.planeName;
                    AnimatePlane plane = planetIcon.GetComponent<AnimatePlane>();

                    plane.moveSpeed = p.planeSpeed;
                    plane.range = p.planeRange;
                    plane.pathNode = new GameObject[3];
                    plane.pathNode[0] = mb;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this "public GameObject[] pathNode = new GameObject[3];" the object pathNode is being overwrited with null value. You don't need to instantiate public GameObjects. You can set the size on Unity's inspector and add the objects there.

Comment: I cant add the objects through the inspector as its a prefab that on instantiation needs its variables set. Thanks for the suggestion though.